# How can I translate an HTML file?

Tags: html, angular, translate

I want to add a translation for an HTML file which contains i.name.
I do have an object called energydensity which contains the data I need for translation.
This actually is a drop-down list and I want to convert that to Chinese.

I have tried this but this is displaying energy.energydensity in the drop-down list.

```
<option value="All">{{allLoads}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let i of ddlLoadType ;">{{'Energy.EnergyDensity.i.Name'}}</option>
    </select>

<option value="All">{{allLoads}}</option>
      <option *ngFor="let i of ddlLoadType ;">{{i.Name}}</option>
    </select>

EN-US json data :
"EnergyDensity": {
    "Heating": "Heating",
                "Cooling": "Cooling",
                "hvac": "HVAC",
                "htg": "Heating",
                "light": "Lighting",
                "plgld": "Plug Load"
    }
```

I want the whole drop-down list to be converted to Chinese.

Comment: there is no chinese in your code, so there can't be any chinese in your output. what have you tried? what didn't work?

Comment: i have a chinese in my chinese json data file i just mentioned english json data only

Comment: dropdown data is coming from i.name , i want to translate those dropdown lists to another language in my case it is chinese , so how can i

Comment: <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>

Comment: how to translate

Answer (score 0):

You might add something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'},'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

This adds a Google Translate Button which translates your page to whatever language the user selects.
There is a full example on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp).

Comment: there is a drop-down list when i click allloads all the values hvac,htg,lighting etc will display and i want to convert them

Comment: Yeah, this script implements a google translator which should translate your whole page to the language the user selected or has set as default.