# Angular 2 drop-down options translation

Tags: angular

I want to change the language of drop-down options

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
        <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

How could I translate to Chinese given my JSON data is:

```
"ConsumptionByLoadType": {
      "ConsumptionByLoadType": "按负载类型分类的电能消耗",
      "hvac": "HVAC",
      "htg": "采暖",
      "light": "照明",
      "plgld": "插座",
      "it": "IT",
      "hotwtr": "热水",
      "undfnd": "未定义",
      "oth": "其他",
      "pmpnaux": "泵和辅助设备"
}
```

Comment: elaborate your question in detail and clear

Comment: Please read: https://angular.io/guide/i18n. Your question isn't getting better the second time. You already posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159147/how-can-i-add-a-translation-to-a-html-file) and no one answered because it is too broad and unclear. This question also has very low quality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i add a translation to a html file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159147/how-can-i-add-a-translation-to-a-html-file)

Comment: What does that JSON have to do with workouts?, if that is the JSON you are displaying, it is already in chinese

Comment: Ok, so the value is the key translated to Chinese

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function for language conversion in typescript file, for example:-

```
    changelanguage(value){
    //your code to change language
    return changedLanguage;
    }
```

And pass {{changelanguage(workout.name)}} instead of {{workout.name}}.

Answer (score 0):

Like @tabishahmed said, just create a function to change the language:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="updateWorkout($event)">
        <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{changelanguage(workout.name)}}</option>
    </select>
```

Since the JSON are the translated key names, you can just do it like this:

```
 changelanguage(value){    
    return ConsumptionByLoadType[value];
    }
```